# Cox model: exclusion of certain subjects at known times

Tags: survival, cox-model, epidemiology

**Background**

We are performing a register based cohort study analysing the effect of influenza exposure (no/yes) on time to event in pregnancy. Exposure period is any time during first trimester. Followup starts from beginning of second trimester until event or end of pregnancy, whichever comes first.
We plan to use the Cox model with exposure as a fixed in time predictor, for analysis.

**Issue**

Some subjects might get flu AFTER the first trimester. This is possible in both those exposed and unexposed during first trimester, though I'm guessing less likely in the exposed group as they will have some immunity (but second infection is still possible).

**Solution**

It has been suggested to exclude all subjects who got flu after first trimester. I am uncertain about this. Aside from reduced power etc., will this not change the study population (restricted to subjects who never get flu in second/third trimester) and hence research question?

**Other thoughts**

The other thing I thought of is to adjust for flu infection during followup as a time varying confounder. That way the study population is regardless of whether subjects become infected after first trimester and hence question is more useful / generalizable? That said, I believe properly modelling the time varying confounder is not trivial e.g. if from records, we know someone is infected on a given date, how long do we assume they have the infection etc.?

Any guidance is much appreciated, particularly with respect to the excusion of subjects approach and my attempt to understand its ramifications.